# Given a KeyPair, how can I verify that the keys contained in this KeyPair are the expected length?

Tags: java, security, cryptography, jca, key-pair

I am writing some Junit tests in which a number of objects of type java.security.KeyPair are generated (from a java.security.KeyPairGenerator)

I am adding some asserts to confirm that the keys contained in these KeyPairs have the expected attributes (the expected algorithm and the expected sizes).

For example, I have added an assert statement to confirm that the algorithm is the expected algorithm using:

```
String expectedAlgorithm = "RSA";
String errorMsg = "The key is not of the expected algorithm";
assertEquals(errorMsg, expectedAlgorithm, privateKey.getAlgorithm());
```

I tried to find some method in KeyPair or in the Keys themselves which returns the size (number of bits) of the keys but I could not find such a method.

I checked the output of the toString() method of the keys to see if this string contains the size of the keys, using:

```
String stringRepresentation = publicKey.toString();
```

I found that for the SunRsaSign provider, the string contains the number of bits in its first line (and therefore it is possible to confirm the key size by parsing this String. But then when I checked the same method for Bouncy Castle, I found that the string does not contain the number of bits. As shown below:

Output of toString() on a key from the RsaSunSign Provider:

```
Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 10827493886854...
  public exponent: 65537
```

Output of toString() on a key from the Bouncy Castle Provider:

```
RSA Public Key
            modulus: 830d0eb805c527e8...
    public exponent: 10001
```

So it is obviously not safe to use the output of the String representation of a key to confirm its size, as we cant know which provider will be used.

So my question is: given a KeyPair (and also given the KeyPairGenerator that was used to generate that KeyPair), is there a provider-neutral way to confirm the size of the Keys in the KeyPair?

Answer (score 0):

The size of an RSA key is defined as the number of bits in the modulus. Note that the modulus is generated in such a way that it is in between 2 ^ (n - 1) and 2 ^ n - 1 (inclusive), so it cannot be smaller than the key size.

So to get the key size of a public or private RSA key, you do the following:

```
int keysize = RSAPublicKey.getModulus().bitLength();
```

You may have to (down)cast your `PublicKey` or `PrivateKey` to `RSAPublicKey` and `RSAPrivate` key before you can access the modulus.

Usually the bit size is on a byte boundary, i.e. the bit size can be divided by 8.